# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int towards my constructor

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, constructor

I've been struggling a bit with templates and apparently classes now. 
It assumes something else of my constructor and wants a type specifier.
This is currently the root of a chunk of my problems in my program, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 if that's information is useful.

This is the .cpp file where the coding is held

```
#include "stacks.h"
#include "main.h"

template <class A_Type> Stack<A_Type>::stacks()
{
     top = -1;
};

template <class A_Type> A_Type Stack<A_Type>::push(A_Type x)
{
    //Checking if stack is full before pushing.
    if (top >= 8)
    {
        cout << "Stack Overflow \n";
    }
    //Stack is not full, then push int/float into stack.
    else
    {
        a[++top] = x;
        cout << "Element Inserted \n";
    }
}

template <class A_Type> A_Type Stack<A_Type>::pop()
{
    if (top < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        A_Type d = a[top--];
        return d;
    }
}

template <class A_Type> A_Type Stack<A_Type>::peak()
{
    A_Type p = a[top];
    return p;
}

//wants to stay as template.
//Changed the A_Type behind Stack to an int. 
template <class A_Type> int Stack<A_Type>::count()
{
    int c = top + 1;
    return c;
}

template <class A_Type> A_Type Stack<A_Type>::IsEmpty()
{
    if (!count())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template class Stack<int>;
template class Stack<float>;
template class Stack<void>;
```

And this is the .h file where the class is inside of.

```
#ifndef CODING03_STACKS_H
#define CODING03_STACKS_H

template <class A_Type> class Stack
{
private:
    int top; // count = top + 1

public:
    //Constructor
    stacks();

    A_Type a[9]; // Stack's max size.
    A_Type push(A_Type x);
    A_Type pop();
    A_Type peak();
    int count();
    A_Type IsEmpty();
};

#endif
```

I was not able to find the answers from similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is called `stacks` while the class is called `Stack` - in C++ the constructors has to have the same name as the class, i.e. `Stack`.